# KeyError raised while CSV file is correctly placed and keys exist in the CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have this Python code:

```
import csv

csvfile = 'stations-nl-2014-01.csv'

try:
    f = open(csvfile, 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')

    for row in reader:
        print(row['name'], '--', row['type'])
finally:
    f.close()
```

I can use the regular csv.reader() method, but I was told using csv.DictReader() is best practise because you can select columns by their names which makes the code more readable. However, when I use the normal csv.reader() method, no error is shown. When I use DictReader, I get the following error:

`print(row['name'], '--', row['type']) 
KeyError: 'name'`

When I change my code to:

```
import csv

csvfile = 'stations-nl-2014-01.csv'

try:
    f = open(csvfile, 'r')
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
finally:
    f.close()
```

...everything works fine. But using csv.DictReader() and selecting rows by their column names raises the error. Anyone know how to fix this? I've double checked the path of the .csv file and the column names and it's all correct (works fine without DictReader).

Comment: does `print row.keys()` give you anything useful?

Comment: Could you give some example rows from your CSV? my initial assumption is that you need `row['Name']`.

Comment: When I execute row.keys() is get this: `dict_keys(['code\tuic\tnaam\tmiddel_naam\tkorte_naam\trdt_url\ttype\tgeo_lat\tgeo_lng'])`

I tried the column names `tnaam` and `ttype`, which are in the dict_keys list, but those also produce the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I searched up file 'stations-nl-2014-01.csv' on the web, and I see that it does not have column 'name'. Column 'type' exists though.

It has the following columns:
code    uic naam    middel_naam korte_naam  rdt_url type    geo_lat geo_lng

Are you sure you shouldn't be looking for row['naam']?

2) If the above doesn't work, you can get a list of keys that your 'row' dictionary contains using row.keys(). This will give you a list of the keys that csv.DictReader actually recognized.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deliberately changed 'naam' which is Dutch to 'name', so people here understand the code better.

When I execute row.keys() is get this: `dict_keys(['code\tuic\tnaam\tmiddel_naam\tkorte_naam\trdt_url\ttype\tgeo_lat\tgeo_lng'])`

I tried the column names `tnaam` and `ttype`, which are in the dict_keys list, but those also produce the same error.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I print the keys and it's there. I print the dict and it's there. I've renamed it and it still happens. I have copied the whole dictionary into a new one and it still happens. No matter what I call the first column it gives me a KeyError.

And it has no problems reading other items, just the first column by its name.

Comment: @CashCow Maybe it's a good idea to create a new topic about this with your code and corresponding CSV file? People might be able to help you better then.

Comment: I found the problem. I just think your question was not very good because it seems rather localised to a file called 'stations-nl-2014-01.csv' that means nothing to anyone who has the issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad question because nobody knows what is in the CSV file.

However I had the same situation and on the first key I was getting key error.
It turns out that the file, which had been created initially in Excel, was saved with UTF-8 encoding and had a silent `'\ufeff'` prefix

My fix was to convert each dict to use ascii-encoded strings

```
def convert_row( row ):
row_dict = {}
for key, value in row.items():
    keyAscii = key.encode('ascii', 'ignore' ).decode()
    valueAscii = value.encode('ascii','ignore').decode()
    row_dict[ keyAscii ] = valueAscii
return row_dict
```

This can also be done with map / lambda e.g.

```
def ascii_encode( str ):
    return str.encode( 'ascii', 'ignore' ).decode()

def convert_row( row ):
    return dict(map( lambda(key,value) :
        (ascii_encode(key),ascii_encode(value) ), row.items() ) )
```

or something like that

The main issue in my answer is the possible requirement to ascii_encode the strings if the file is utf-8.

Comment: This fixed my issue, the .csv file which were created via excel contains the following line before the first column name " {'\ufeffid':. " .......

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, srooy.

The problem is pretty trivial. I just had it, came here because I was in doubt, but I was already suspecting what the cause was. It took me a minute two figure it out, but as I see that nobody actually answered it, I will do that to save somebody some work.

In short, this is my code (it' s the real thing, it's a silly example I was working on). This is the CSV:

```
name,surname  
Manuel,van der Heide
Pedro-Paco,Bulebú Dancé-Avecmuâ
Dietrich, von dem Bach-Schleußenhübner zu Jägerstein
Jan, ter Kraale
Robert-Jan, Fietsema
François, le Felpudin
Manon, van Brummen
Menno, 't Hof
Alfonso, Décimo Elsabio
Karl-Heinz, von Bubbler
Carlos, Pi García
Luise, Klaver-Hover
Joao, da Silva Fernandes do Pinhal
```

The names are just stupid ones I made up for testing variations of surnames.

And this is the pretty silly script. I was only using it to check how it looked like before starting to work. I want to try a few things to generate meaningful login names, but that is not relevant here. So of completeness's sake here it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import argparse,csv

# Create the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f','--file')
args = parser.parse_args()

csv_input = args.file
# print(args.file.readlines())


with open(csv_input, mode='r') as csvito:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvito)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        print(f'\t{row["name"]} - {row["surname"]}')
        line_count += 1
    print
```

Note that the error has nothing to do with the code (well, kinda).

The simple answer:

*There are two empty spaces after the last column. That's all*

To correct it, just remove the empty spaces, add a comma after the last word.

There may be more elegant solutions (you can use the str.strip() function with Pandas read_csv), but I just wanted to add my quick five cents :)

Comment: You're a legend for answering 8 years later. Thanks. This was for a university assignment.